# How to I serve angular files with node http library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am converting my app from Express to use Node's simple `http` library due to deployment complications with using Express. In Express to serve my client side angular files I have the following line:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/app/'));
```

How can I achieve the same thing using node's `http` module?

Please, no comments/questions on why I am not using Express or suggestions on why I should use Express. The reason for not using Express is outside the scope of this post. I just really need to be able to serve my frontend using Node's `http` library. Thanks!

Comment: You can go look at the [implementation of `express.static()` on Github](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js) and see exactly what it does.  In a nutshell, you need your http handler to check the incoming url path to see if it starts with your root.  If it does, then it needs to find the corresponding file that is being requested from the rest of the URL, get that file in the file system and return it as the http response.

Comment: you will need to write about a paragraph of code to (mostly) replace that. once you match up url path to fs path, you can just pipe a file read stream to the server res stream.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use express, but a standalone static-server module:

```
var static = require('node-static');

//
// Create a node-static server instance to serve the './public' folder
//
var file = new static.Server('./public');

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        //
        // Serve files!
        //
        file.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();
}).listen(8080);
```

[node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static)

This article has some further details as well, but recommends something like node-static, for security purposes:
[How to serve static files](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files)